# If the gates of heaven are closed to fallen angels but not to humans, how would it be for an angel-human hybrid?

Tags: fantasy-races

Asking because it's a major plot point in my novel, which I'm currently working on. The question is just what it is - heaven is closed to fallen angels because of course it is, but it's not the case for humans. Would a hybrid, with angel-human parentage, be any different?

Note: my story does not follow the intricacies of real-life religions. So any speculation regarding what the Bible or any other book says about the Nephilim are out.

Another note: Even if I choose to make Heaven accessible to this one character, would it appear plausible or a cheap cop-out on my part as the writer?

Comment: Please read description of [tag:worldbuilding-process] - it is **not** for this type of question. There is no tag to say "I'm in the process of world building" because if you are asking on this site, then of course you are.

Comment: VtC as primarily opinion based. If you are not using Bible or any other material from existing religions, but you are making this up yourself, then rules of course will be exactly as your story needs them. "plausible or a cheap cop-out" is purely an opinion.

Comment: your story, your rules. This holds also for the gatekeeper of heaven.

Comment: @Mołot you're right I apologize. I changed it accordingly. I hope this new one is appropriate

Comment: The question about whether it's a "cheap cop-out" may be more worthwhile on writers.se

Comment: What is "heaven"? What are "angels"? What do you mean by "accessible" -- in common religions humans cannot access heaven, only human *souls* can.

Comment: It depends on how your hybridization process works. Say that the left side of the character is demonic, and the right side is human. He would be able to stand with his right side in heaven, but his left side would be stuck at the door.

Comment: If you are using aspects of a Christian paradigm concerning heaven, then entrance to heaven would be based on the actions & attitudes of *individuals* not groups. Fallen angels would be denied entrance to heaven because of their individual actions & attitudes. A hybrid angel-human would be judged by the same criteria. They, like everyone else, angel or human, cannot be held responsible for someone else's actions or attitudes, only for their own. If the *individual* angel-human hybrid is deemed worthy of entrance to heaven they will be granted entrance, if not, they won't. ...

Comment: ... Entrance to heaven is should be based on merit, not association.

Answer (score 2):

**You have to introduce some heavenly rules**

Example, The [Good Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good_Place) Except fallen angels, you can say that human-angel hybrids require more "good points" than usual humans. Or less. Your decision :)

**Bible can be good rulebook to start** Oh my, calling the Bible as a [rulebook](https://dnd.wizards.com/what-is-dnd/basic-rules) will not give me any good points, but you have to consider looking into Bible, because:

- Your story appears to be based on Christianity
- Therefore, reader of the story will expect it to follow at least some Christian rules.

I know I am melding my answer with [writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) advice, but to sum it up:

- If you want worldbuilding advice, the answer is: Introduce rules. Even if you don't mention them anywhere
- If you want writing advice, ask on [Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 2):

The normal way is to say that the gates to heaven/hell/... check how much demon/fallen angel/... you have in yourself - everyone's a little evil inside, but normal humans that are ~90 % human shouldn't have any problems. There should be some sort of safety margin.

You can then look at other media to get an idea for how hybrids work. In Dungeons and Dragons for example you often encounter hybrids - Aasimar (half-angel), Tiefling (half-devil), Half-Orc (...), Half-Elf (...creative), ...

These are often fighting with their different sides of their heritage. Some may be good, some may be bad, some feel the bad stuff but fight it to be good, ...

By stating that your gates are not checking for *heritage*, but for *current internal status* you could simply say that your character is enough *Good* to pass the gates of heaven, whereas most demons/fallen angels/... are inherently evil and can't pass. This opens up the possibility of letting one or two through that are not-completely-evil. Or brainwashed. Or anything else that would allow them to trust that what they are doing is *Good*.

Only allowing this for one person is too simple. "Yeah, he's special" will bore most readers. But an intricate mechanism that allows errors will introduce a lot of possibilties.

Answer (score 2):

If you take this in a literal context of being. We have three different species.

- Angels
- Fallen Angels
- Humans

If heaven is accessible to two species then the question is, is the hybrid of a fallen angel or of an angel. If the latter, then they get to go to heaven. If the former, then it becomes complex in the format of what side of their hybrid do they renounce, and/or if they are able to change their species format to leave behind their fallen angel heritage.

How you decide to present these species, whether in characteristics or psychology is yours and yours alone.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, my friend is blowing in the Bible. Or in the comments to part II.

What you are basically asking is, can an entity inherit a sin that was committed by it's ancestor and without removing it go to heaven.

In common language we call that "baptism to remove original sin".
So anything goes in your story because your heaven, your rules. You can allow it to enter, you can split the person in two and allow only half (left or right or upper body). You can say that "not your fault, go on" "not your fault but do some feat to prove yourself".

Or you can create place for such hybrids, call it purgatory or something.

Comment: any speculation regarding what the Bible or any other book says about the Nephilim are out. (OP)

Comment: There is no mention about nephilim. They are mentioned in the first part of Bible. I'm talking about second part. This is not a divagation about certain entities, it's about idea of "contaminated" entering prohibited zones. And we've been through this, purgatory, baptism, taking a bath before entering temple, doing godlike feats.

Answer (score 1):

The heaven is the place of the god and who gets in is up to the god. Generally angels get in because they work there, fallen angels do not because do not. Access to heaven is basically an employee benefit.

This extends to mortals. If you do the gods work, after you die you'll get promoted to continue yor work for god in the heaven.

I do not see any reason why it should make a difference what the character is. If he is capable of doing the gods work and has done so while living, dying will not make the god say "You are fired!". To him death is not a real obstacle or an excuse for employees to stop working. At most if angels have a prejudice for halfs the god might assign the person on off-heaven duty. Or make a point of assigning him to highly visible position in heaven so that nobody forgets who is the boss.

Conversely if the characters did not do gods work while alive, god will have no reason to invite them to heaven. Again it makes no difference what one of their parents was.

Although hereditary priesthoods and pacts between gods and entire nations are a possibility. But even if you "inherit the work" you'd still have to actually do it. Although technically a covenant between a god and a nation might have the nation doing the work and all the people of the nation getting the employee benefits as long as the nation as a whole does its part.